# Efficient way to automate from combinations of sensor states

Tags: home-automation

I'm trying to make an automation that creates [persistent notification](https://home-assistant.io/components/persistent_notification/) after checking via [mi flora](https://home-assistant.io/components/sensor.miflora/) which of my five plants need watering. So far, the only way I can see that being possible is by using [conditions](https://home-assistant.io/docs/scripts/conditions/) that checks for every possible combination of sensor states and has an answer prepared for each outcome. The number of possible outcomes would be 32. Surely there must be a more efficient way of doing this, especially since I'm waiting for 5 more sensors to arrive. Anyone know of a way?

Comment: I would include the number(s) of the sensor in the notification.  Personally I would set a bit or bits in a uint64_t (C stdint.h) and return that value.

Comment: That sounds very promising. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: In C and the languages based on C's syntax X |= (1<<Y) to set bit Y.  if  (X & (1<<Y)) to check a bit,